# Issue in rpy2 - ri2py transforming NA incorrectly

Tags: python, r, pandas, rpy2

I'm trying to interface some R code via Python, but the converting the data back to a pandas object isn't handling NA values correctly.

Sample R code:

```
dummy_call_method1 <- function(argument) {
    col_a <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
    col_b <- c(1, NA, 11, 12)
    return(data.frame(col_a, col_b))
}

dummy_call_method2 <- function(argument) {
    col_a <- c("A", "A", "B", "B")
    col_b <- c("one", NA, "eleven", "twelve")
    return(data.frame(col_a, col_b))
}
```

Sample Python code:

```
import os
import rpy2
from rpy2 import rinterface, robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri

def r_source(base_dir, filename):
    r_script = os.path.join(base_dir, filename)
    r_src = rpy2.robjects.r['source']
    r_src(r_script)

def r_call_function(func_name, *args):
    func = rpy2.robjects.r[func_name]
    result = func(*args)
    return result

r_source('~/workspace/', 'test.R')

dummy_results1 = r_call_function("dummy_call_method1", "")
dummy_results2 = r_call_function("dummy_call_method2", "")

print dummy_results1
print rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri.ri2py(dummy_results)
print dummy_results2
print rpy2.robjects.pandas2ri.ri2py(dummy_results2)
```

I would expect for both calls to ri2py to replace the NA value in the dummy call with None and NaN, respectively. However, while the latter is working as expected, the former is replacing the NA with "Eleven" for some reason - I don't know if it's reading in an uninitialized pointer or what.

Here's the output, with the unexpected behavior noted:

```
  col_a    col_b
1     A        1
2     A       NA
3     B       11
4     B       12

  col_a     col_b
1     A       1.0
2     A       NaN
3     B      11.0
4     B      12.0

  col_a     col_b
1     A       one
2     A      <NA>
3     B    eleven
4     B    twelve

  col_a      col_b
1     A        one
2     A     eleven     #This is incorrect
3     B     eleven
4     B     twelve
```

Comment: Issue definitely seems to be related to NA types in a FactorVector - dummy_results2 is two FactorVectors for the values, but dummy_results1 is FloatVectors. Coercing in the R side with "stringsAsFactors = FALSE" in the data.frame avoids the issue, but my preference is to solve this on the python side as I cannot always change the R source I'm calling